# Is a Central Mercurial repo necessary?

Tags: mercurial

Trying to find a workable workflow for multiple developers in our Coldfusion shop before we implement.

Currently, most of us (still) work directly in production. I want to change that.

If each developer has their own repo and there are repo's on the test and prod web servers, what is the value in a 'central' repository? What value does something like BitBucket add in this scenario?

Comment: Don't think of a "Central Repository" as a centralized VCS. Rather, think of it as a "synchronization point" between developers - it's just another ("distributed, but special") repository clone. While one of the love-hate relationships I have with Hg, I recommend Hg Queues are used on the WCs and developers should not be discouraged from local clones if it fits their workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a central repository, you can put the development into a dev branch and leave the production branch for only bugfixes. Also, I think it is a bad idea to run off a mercurial repo in a production environment. Think about a regular deploy strategy to decouple the production server from the repository.

But I must admit, that I have no experience in Coldfusion, maybe there it is totally okay to run directly from a repository.

Answer (score 0):

The chief advantages of bitbucket are the lack of server setup/maintenance/backup, you can get to it anywhere you have internet access.

@luksch was right to question running prod directly from a cloned repo.  At a minimum you want to make sure you're not serving up the .hg directory.  I'd encourage you to use some kind of deployment script that would grab the source at a tag from mercurial package it, place it on the repo and also restart or do anything the CF server needs.

The best experience I had with cold fusion (much like I have a best root canal) was when we ditched adobe's server and used [railo](http://www.getrailo.org/), this freed us up from paying adobe for licenses on all our servers as well as made it easy to package the app and it's runtime in a war - thus making deployment super easy.

Answer (score 0):

A central repo hosted on BitBucket or your company's servers (assuming they are physically protected and backed up) gives you the advantage of reliably having them available and business continuity in case of something really bad happening.

Multiple copies of the repository are good if a hard drive with one of them crashes.  But if fire or theft wipes out all of the hard drives with the repos (which I have read one case of that happening) it leaves you with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best things about distributed version control is that it allows you to design your workflow around your own development processes. You do not need a central repository but many projects end up using one.

A central repository is a great way of keeping track of the latest version of the code base. This means that when a developer wants to get a copy of the latest code they always know where to pull / clone from rather than having to ask around the team.

Having a central repository doesn't limit you in any way, you can still use other workflows along side it. For example if a few members of the team are working on a feature they can push and pull between their development repositories without pushing to the central repository.